# "Breaking News" feature for OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos

Recently I have gotten more and more "Breaking News" features from the NY Times which appear on my desktop.

(1) How did I initiate this feature?

(2) How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While visiting the New York Times website, you (probably unwittingly) allowed the site to send push notifications to you on your Mac, but removing them is very simple:

1. Open Safari
2. In the menu bar, click Safari->Preferences->Notifications
3. Once there, check the box for "Deny" to the right of "The New York Times".

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your questions:

### How did I turn this on?

You may have hit the <kbd>return</kbd> key when seeing this dialog at your first visit to The New York Times:

[image: NY Times allow notifications dialog]

### How do I turn this off?

Follow [RedEagle2000's answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204393/120171)

[image]